# jquery-autocomplete (standalone) set width

Tags: javascript, jquery-autocomplete

I'm happily using this autocompleter: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/.

I need to change the width of the generated ul list, but can't do it through CSS:

```
.acResults {
    width: 348px;
}
```

it seems that the width is set in javascript every time a result is generated as:

```
$('.acResults').width(348);
```

works, but only once (overwritten after typing).
I've tried using the above function in both "showResult" and "onItemSelect", but both are overwritten immediately afterwards.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the style using `!important` although it's not a good practice. Example:

```
.acResults {
    width: 348px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove (or alter) the lines in your local copy of the plugin that set the width of the list, i.e.:

```
extraWidth = this.dom.$results.outerWidth() - this.dom.$results.width();
this.dom.$results.width(this.dom.$elem.outerWidth() - extraWidth);
```

You could change it to:

```
this.dom.$results
    .width(Math.max(this.dom.$elem.outerWidth() - extraWidth, 348));
```

If you're using the minified version, grab the unminified version, alter it, and run it through your minifier of choice.

Alternatively, you could create a patch that takes in a minimum list width option and submit it to dylan.verheul or submit a new feature request on the [issues page](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/issues/list) perhaps.

Comment: I don't like editing the plugin itself, but I will submit an issue.

Answer (score 0):

just increase the width of the 'ac_results'  and it will hide the y-overflow

```
.ac_results ul {
width: 180px;
/* 
increase width to hide overflow
*/
list-style-position: outside;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

}